# C: Where should I free my pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, recursion, free

I'm a student and I'm trying to complete a task in C right now.

I've written an algorithm, which works fine so far. It gets a file to detect if the included logical expression is satisfiable (SAT-Solver). The problem is, that I get a Segementation Fault after a while, when I'm trying to use it with bigger files (about 60MB). I think it is, because I use malloc a couple times, but I don't free that memory yet, because I don't know where to put the free() expresseions.

There's one method, which calls itself twice everytime. The code looks like this:

```
int DPLL (int *pointer, int variablen, int anzahlklauseln)
{
int newliteral;
int neueklauseln;
int *neuphi;
int *neuphi2;
int *unitclauses;
int *pureliterals;
int offsetzaehler;
int rek1, rek2;

klauseln = anzahlklauseln;
unitclauses = (int *) malloc(klauseln * sizeof(int));
pureliterals = (int *) malloc(variablen * sizeof(int));

if (isEmpty())
{
    return 1;

}

if (ContainsEmptyClause(pointer, variablen))
{
    return 0;
}

unitClauses(pointer, variablen, unitclauses);
if (unsatisfiable)
{
    unsatisfiable = 0;
    return 0;
}

int iunitclauses = 0;
while (unitclauses[iunitclauses] != 0)
{
    unitPropagate(pointer, variablen, unitclauses[iunitclauses++]);
}

if (quicksati(pointer, variablen))
{
    return 1;
}

pureLiterals(pointer, variablen, pureliterals);

int ipureliterals = 0;
while (pureliterals[ipureliterals] != 0)
{
    pureLiteralAssign(pointer, variablen, pureliterals[ipureliterals++]);
}

if (quicksati(pointer, variablen))
{
    return 1;
}

newliteral = chooseliteral(pointer, variablen);

neuphi = (int*) malloc(variablen * (klauseln + 1) * sizeof(int));
neuphi2 = (int*) malloc(variablen * (klauseln + 1) * sizeof(int));

int *hilfspointer = pointer;

offsetzaehler = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < (klauseln +1); ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < variablen; ++j)
    {
        if (i == klauseln)
        {
            neuphi[offsetzaehler] = 0;
            neuphi2[offsetzaehler] = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            neuphi[offsetzaehler] = *hilfspointer;
            neuphi2[offsetzaehler++] = *hilfspointer++;
        }
    }
}

neueklauseln = klauseln + 1;

addClause(neuphi, variablen, newliteral);
addClause(neuphi2, variablen, (-newliteral));

if (DPLL(neuphi, variablen, neueklauseln))
{
    return 1;
}
else
{
    return DPLL(neuphi2, variablen, neueklauseln);
}
}
```

Now I thought I should edit the last lines like this:

```
rek1 = DPLL(neuphi, variablen, neueklauseln);
rek2 = DPLL(neuphi2, variablen, neueklauseln);

free(neuphi);
free(neuphi2);
free(unitclauses);
free(pureliterals);

return rek1 || rek2;
```

But then I'll get segmentation fault errors for files, which worked before.

Then I tried it like this:

```
if (DPLL(neuphi, variablen, neueklauseln))
{
    return 1;
}
else
{
    free(neuphi);
    free(unitclauses);
    free(pureliterals);
    rek1 = DPLL(neuphi2, variablen, neueklauseln);
    free(neuphi2);
    return rek1;
}
```

But then I'd get even more Segmentation Faults.

So any C experts here, who'd like to help me? Thanks alot! :)

Comment: missing `free`'s will not cause a `segmentation fault`, suppose that you need all that data at once, why would you call `free`? You should call `free` when you don't need it anymore. One thing wrong with your code is that you don't check the success of `malloc` but I don't think that's the cause of the `segmentation fault` although that could be one.

Comment: How many times you estimate `DPLL` to call itself? that could be a problem.

Comment: Is there in the `some magic` some magic to return from the function?

Comment: @user300234 that's what im thinking, he encountered a Stack Overflow to ask Stack Overflow about.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comments. The method contains several exit conditions. I edited the full code above.

Answer (score 1):

Your recursion doesn't have an exit condition, so the program will encounter segmentation fault when it hits stack overflow or when your malloc call returns null pointer as consequence of running out of heap memory, whatever happens first.

Comment: there should be a badge for using "stack overflow" correctly in an answer on stack overflow.